# Google Dart Paper Button Selector

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I cannot seem to create a paper button that allows me to use it as a selector for closing a paper-dialog.  I have a feeling this is a CSS issue, but I could be wrong.  The button gets created after all of the elements and when you switch tabs, it essentially re-creates the button into a new div.  Below is my code for the CSS, Dialog setup, and the Dart code.  Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Dart and markup:

```dart
PaperButton button;


button = new PaperButton();
button.label = "Close";
settingsDialog.children.add(button);

settingsDialog.autoCloseDisabled = true;
settingsDialog.closeSelector = "paper-button";


<paper-dialog id="properties" style='background-color:#fbfbfb; margin: 0 auto; border-style: double; border-color: #FEB33F; position:fixed;'>

 <paper-tabs id="Tabs" noink="true" selected="{{page}}" style='width:250px; height:30px; color:#333333;'>
      <paper-tab id="sTab">S</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab id="uTab">U</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

    <core-pages selected="{{page}}">
      <div id="s">
      <!--Page one -->
      </div>
      <div id="u">
      <!--Page two -->
      </div>
    </core-pages>
 </paper-dialog>
```

CSS:

```dart
paper-button 
{
margin-top:7%;
float:right;
margin-bottom: -15px;
background-color:#f0f0f0;
border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-left: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
width:65px;
height:45px;
position:fixed;
margin-left:25%;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a paper-button you should use `paper-button` as selector. Why do you think `button` is a valid selector for a `paper-button`?

Comment: What about just adding an `affirmative` or `dismissive` attribute to the button to use the default behavior?

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of that?  I cannot seem to find one.

Comment: `new PaperButton()..attributes['affirmative'] = true;`

Comment: This doesn't work because Dart says a value of bool cannot be assigned of type String.

Comment: Sorry, '= "true";` then.